# Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete using Java and Rexster

Tags: titan, rexster

I want to manage a graph (create, delete and update vertexes and edges) remotely using Java.
I have all my DAO layer implemented, using Blueprints and a TitanGraph object to access and manipulate graph information.

I thought that installing Rexster and replacing the TitanGraph factory with a remote connection will be enough. But after install Rexster, seems that it is not possible create a TitanGraph object connected to Rexster.

In the documentation talk about two options to work with Rexster:

- Using RexsterClient : <del>But it is only possible to use Gremlin, so it
  is not possible to create/delete/update information.</del> It is possible to create/delete/update executing Groovy scripts, as said @stephen-mallette.
- Using Rexster HTTP Rest API: It is possible, but I need rewrite all
  my DAO layer.

My question is: How to create/update/delete vertex/edge using Java and a remote Rexster server? Where are there examples?

Regards and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by this:

> Using RexsterClient : But it is only possible to use Gremlin, so it is not possible to create/delete/update information.

`RexsterClient` issues Gremlin scripts to Rexster.  While we typically think of Gremlin as a traversal language for querying the graph, it is perfectly capable of mutating a graph as well.  The following is perfectly valid Gremlin:

```
v = g.addVertex()
v.setProperty("name","bill")
```

So, in that sense you could certainly issue remote Gremlin that modified the graph from `RexsterClient`.    However, in your case, you already have DAO code.  Why not re-use that code and simply host it in Rexster?

1. Copy your jar containing your DAO code to Rexster `/ext` directory
2. Modify `rexster.xml` to include your package imports from your jar for the classes you want to have available to you: `<imports>com.myco.dao.*</imports>`
3. Start Rexster

At that point, when you use `RexsterClient`, you should be able to access those DAO classes in the Gremlin scripts that you send.

Comment: Hi @stephen-mallette I thought in  host DAO in Rexster, but I don't want deploy in all Rexster server and restart all, after each new version deployment. In reference to use Gremlin, I don't like the idea of hardcore big Groovy script to set a lot of properties.
I think that Blueprints / Rexster need a transactional API to work remotely, like JDBC.

Comment: Yeah - the restart is sorta painful, though you can mitigate that pain with a load-balancer and rolling restart or full auto-replacement of the Rexster instances.  That's a relatively easy workaround if you are in a virtual environment.  I wouldn't envision sending "big groovy scripts".  If you have the right level of abstraction in your DAO, wouldn't a script just be: `UserDAO.createUser([name:"stephen",favoriteColor:"green"])`?

Comment: Finally, there is no "remote Blueprints API - we tried to do that a couple of times and it didn't turn out well.  Not sure how easy that would be to add to Gremlin Server (Rexster's replacement) in TinkerPop3.  Right now, Gremlin Server follows Rexster's pattern for the most part.  In some respect it might be harder given that TinkerPop3 merges Blueprints/Gremlin structures to some degree.  Perhaps the only way that it is easier, lies in the Gremlin Server extension model which is a more flexible than Rexster's.

Comment: Hi Stephen. In this moment, I am going to use Rexster Rest API and don't take care over transactionality. If we found money / investors to our project, I can work trying to fill this gap ("remote Blueprints API") maybe in a new opensource project or under the umbrella of TinkerPop.